# GLSL Shader - Change Hue/Saturation/Brightness

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, opengl-es2, fragment-shader

I'm trying to change the hue of an image using a GLSL fragment shader. I want to achieve something similar to Photoshop's Hue/Saturation Adjustment layer.

In the following image you can see what I've got so far. I want to change the hue of the green square so it looks like the red square on the right, but with this shader I get a half red half pink square (the square in the middle).
[image]

What I'm doing in the fragment shader is converting the texture's color to HSV, then I add the HSV color that I get from the vertex shader to it and I convert the color back to RGB.
What am I doing wrong?

Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec3 vHSV;
uniform sampler2D sTexture;

vec3 convertRGBtoHSV(vec3 rgbColor) {
    float r = rgbColor[0];
    float g = rgbColor[1];
    float b = rgbColor[2];
    float colorMax = max(max(r,g), b);
    float colorMin = min(min(r,g), b);
    float delta = colorMax - colorMin;
    float h = 0.0;
    float s = 0.0;
    float v = colorMax;
    vec3 hsv = vec3(0.0);
    if (colorMax != 0.0) {
      s = (colorMax - colorMin ) / colorMax;
    }
    if (delta != 0.0) {
        if (r == colorMax) {
            h = (g - b) / delta;
        } else if (g == colorMax) {        
            h = 2.0 + (b - r) / delta;
        } else {    
            h = 4.0 + (r - g) / delta;
        }
        h *= 60.0;
        if (h < 0.0) {
            h += 360.0;
        }
    }
    hsv[0] = h;
    hsv[1] = s;
    hsv[2] = v;
    return hsv;
}
vec3 convertHSVtoRGB(vec3 hsvColor) {
    float h = hsvColor.x;
    float s = hsvColor.y;
    float v = hsvColor.z;
    if (s == 0.0) {
        return vec3(v, v, v);
    }
    if (h == 360.0) {
        h = 0.0;
    }
    int hi = int(h);
    float f = h - float(hi);
    float p = v * (1.0 - s);
    float q = v * (1.0 - (s * f));
    float t = v * (1.0 - (s * (1.0 - f)));
    vec3 rgb;
    if (hi == 0) {
        rgb = vec3(v, t, p);
    } else if (hi == 1) {
        rgb = vec3(q, v, p);
    } else if (hi == 2) {
        rgb = vec3(p, v, t);
    } if(hi == 3) {
        rgb = vec3(p, q, v);
    } else if (hi == 4) {
        rgb = vec3(t, p, v);
    } else {
        rgb = vec3(v, p, q);
    }
    return rgb;
}
void main() {
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
    vec3 fragRGB = textureColor.rgb;
    vec3 fragHSV = convertRGBtoHSV(fragRGB);
    fragHSV += vHSV;
    fragHSV.x = mod(fragHSV.x, 360.0);
    fragHSV.y = mod(fragHSV.y, 1.0);
    fragHSV.z = mod(fragHSV.z, 1.0);
    fragRGB = convertHSVtoRGB(fragHSV);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(convertHSVtoRGB(fragHSV), textureColor.w);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Using the functions Sam Hocevar provided in his answer, the problem with pink bands is solved, but I can only reach half of the color spectrum. I can change the hue from red to green, but I can't change it to blue or pink.
[image]

In the fragment shader, I'm doing this now:

```
void main() {
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
    vec3 fragRGB = textureColor.rgb;
    vec3 fragHSV = rgb2hsv(fragRGB);
    float h = vHSV.x / 360.0;
    fragHSV.x *= h;
    fragHSV.yz *= vHSV.yz;
    fragHSV.x = mod(fragHSV.x, 1.0);
    fragHSV.y = mod(fragHSV.y, 1.0);
    fragHSV.z = mod(fragHSV.z, 1.0);
    fragRGB = hsv2rgb(fragHSV);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(hsv2rgb(fragHSV), textureColor.w);
}
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `int hi = int(h/60.0); float f = h/60.0 - float(hi);` instead of `int hi = int(h); float f = h - float(hi);`? Don't know if that's causing it, though.

Comment: @kolrabi I've tried that but I was still getting pink bands. I've finally solved that problem with the conversion functions that Sam Hocevar provided in his answer.

Comment: @mivic: We don't put answers in questions. If you found the answer on your own, then post an answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nicol Bolas suggested in the original post's comments, I'm posting the solution to my problem in a separate answer.

The first issue was the image being rendered with pink bands, as the image in the original post shows. I fixed it using the functions Sam Hocevar provided in his answer (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/59808/22302).

The second issue was that I was multiplying the hue of the texture's pixel by the value I was sending to the shader, which is meant to be an offset from the textures's pixel hue, so I had to perform an addition instead of a multiplication.
I still perform a multiplication for saturation and brightness because I get a weird behaviour otherwise, and I don't really need incrementing them further than the original texture's saturation or brightness at the moment.

This is the main() method of the shader I'm using right now. With this I can shift hue from 0º to 360º, desaturate the image, and reduce brightness.

```
void main() {
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
    vec3 fragRGB = textureColor.rgb;
    vec3 fragHSV = rgb2hsv(fragRGB).xyz;
    fragHSV.x += vHSV.x / 360.0;
    fragHSV.yz *= vHSV.yz;
    fragHSV.xyz = mod(fragHSV.xyz, 1.0);
    fragRGB = hsv2rgb(fragHSV);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(fragRGB, textureColor.w);
}
```

Comment: tip: you probably want to `mod()` the hue, but saturation and brightness you may want to `clamp()` instead.

Comment: Hi, do you convert also saturation and brightness values from {-100,  100} range?

Comment: The above main() with function from sam's answer produce black holes on some images where brightness is set to 1. I changed the main() so that hue is modded and sat/brightness are clamped as suggested by Gustavo. Seem like it solved the problem.

Answer (score 31):

These functions will perform very badly. I suggest using functions that are written with the GPU in mind. Here are mine:

```
vec3 rgb2hsv(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
    vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));

    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    float e = 1.0e-10;
    return vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
}

vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}
```

Note that for these functions the range for `H` is [0…1] instead of [0…360], so you will have to adapt your input.

Source:
http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/07/27/rgb-to-hsv-in-glsl

Comment: Using these functions solved the problem. No more pink bands. But I think I'm still doing something wrong. I've edited my original post with more information. Thanks.

Comment: Really interesting! Can you explain why these functions perform better? What is like "to have the GPU in mind"?

Comment: @Marco GPUs aren’t very good at handling large `if()` constructs, but are good at vector operations (parallel operations on several scalar values). The above functions never use `if()`, try to parallelise operations, and in general they use fewer instructions. These are usually good indicators that they are going to be faster.

Comment: Are these functions exactly equivalent to the standard HSV formulas (ignoring rounding errors), or are they an approximation?